# PHP 7.0/Yii 1/MS Sql Server 2008: PHP is unable to find the driver

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, yii

**Problem in a few words**
When running a PHP script (precisely, an Yii 1.1 ConsoleCommand) that must connect to my sql server, I got

```
CDbException: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: 
could not find driver in ... /CDbConnection.php:399
```

I'm sure I have driver compiled and installed and php.ini configured.

**Environment**

```
$ php -version
PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )

$  lsb_release  -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

$ apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
```

**Yii DB config**

```
"sql_server_db" => array (
        'class'                 => "CDbConnection",
        'connectionString'      => 'dblib:host=SQL-SERVER;dbname=at6_rp',
        'enableParamLogging'    => false,
        'username'              => '<hidden>',
        'password'              => '<hidden>',
        'charset'               => 'utf8',
    ),
```

I've an identical copy of my Yii 1 app running well on an other machine with an old Ubuntu 8 and php 5.2. So *I think* my connection string is right.

**Yii code - point where throwed the error**

> See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/db/CDbConnection.php#L382-L409

**For documentation, I report here, step-by-step what I did to install the drivers**

> I followed instructions found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

**Step 1: Install PHP extensions**

Here i avoided installation of `php7.0` because I already have it

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get -y install php7.0-fpm php-pear php7.0-dev mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt php-mbstring php7.0-xml re2c gcc g++
```

**Step 2: Install pre-requisites**

```
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql mssql-tools 
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev-utf16 unixodbc-utf16 odbcinst1debian2-utf16
```

I didn't setup of apache, I already have it.

**Step 4: Install the Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server**

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

Above rows installed the v4.0.8

**Step 5: Add the Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server to php.ini**

```
echo "extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
echo "extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
echo "extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
echo "extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

I verified: these lines are both in `apache2/php.ini` and in  `cli/php.ini`

**Step 6: Restart Apache to load the new php.ini file**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Anyway: the problem is still here. When I run the php script I got

> CDbException: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: 
>   could not find driver in 
>   ... cut .. /yii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:399

**UPDATE 1:**

As suggested, I restarted `php-fpm`

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service
```

No, errors, but the problem with connection is stille here

Comment: Have you restarted your php-fpm process?

Comment: I tried `sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service`. No errors, but no output. Anyway  same problem !

Comment: Are you sure you've updated the correct php.ini? if memory serves correctly, FPM uses a different one than if mod_php is used. Check `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on a page on your server to make sure you've updated the right one.

Comment: Well, I see `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`, so from web-side it looks ok, but I see reference to sqlsrv but not to pdo_sqlsrv ....and the pdo version is NEEDED by Yii

Comment: @realtebo, you need to add the pdo reference as well. Can you confirm if sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv are indeed added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with a simply ...

```
sudo apt install php7.0-sybase
```

No more configs to add, no restart required.

Found here: [Linux - PHP 7.0 and MSSQL (Microsoft SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377338/linux-php-7-0-and-mssql-microsoft-sql) (but not is the accepted answer in that case)