# "Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' "Cenos7 PHP7.2.10

Tags: php, linux

I have overlook at this issue [Linux - PHP 7.0 and MSSQL (Microsoft SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377338/linux-php-7-0-and-mssql-microsoft-sql)

and I am sure did exactly what MS told me to do in this page
[installing-the-drivers-on-red-hat-7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#installing-the-drivers-on-red-hat-7)
howevey, i stiil got the error when type 'php -v':

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so
>   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol:
>   php_pdo_register_driver), /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so
>   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP 7.2.10
>   (cli) (built: Sep 15 2018 07:10:58) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend
>   Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend 
>   Technologies

I never modify the php.ini,

> [user@tssvr php.d]$ pwd
>
> /etc/php.d
>
> [user@tssvr php.d]$ ls
>
> 20-sqlsrv.ini      ctype.ini  fileinfo.ini  gmp.ini    mbstring.ini               pdo.ini         shmop.ini      tokenizer.ini  xmlwriter.ini
>   30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini  curl.ini   ftp.ini       iconv.ini  mysqli.ini                 pdo_mysql.ini   simplexml.ini  xml.ini        xsl.ini
>   bz2.ini            dom.ini    gd.ini        intl.ini   opcache-default.blacklist  pdo_sqlite.ini  sockets.ini    xmlreader.ini  zip.ini
>   calendar.ini       exif.ini   gettext.ini   json.ini   opcache.ini                phar.ini        sqlite3.ini    xml_wddx.ini
>
> [user@tssvr php.d]$ cat 20-sqlsrv.ini
>
> extension=sqlsrv.so
>
> [user@tssvr php.d]$ cat 30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini
>
> extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so

it seems that the sqlsrv.so is good, but the pho_sqlsrv.so just can't work correctly,,although i notice that double 'so' appear: 'pdo_sqlsrv.so.so' ,
can any guys can help me through this ,many thanks.

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: I'm having this exact issue.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue...

Answer (score 3):

The proper order to load the modules is:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

One can either put these into one `.ini` file - or use numbered `.ini` files.

Loading them in alphabetical order (which is the default) won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Type in terminal linux centos 7 :

1. `php --ini`
2. `find /etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini`
3. Edit the file and append `extension=sqlsrv.so  extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so`

note: comment `extension extension=sqlsrv.so , extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so` in `/etc/php.ini`

4. reboot system
5. `php -m` - you see loaded module

Comment: @Stefan That was a perfect solution for my case on centos 8 php7.2

Comment: You're great, it fixed the problem for sure

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.xx. I finally got it to work on Ubuntu 18.04 and pretty sure this will work on 20.xx as well.

This is for PHP 7.1 so if you are not using 7.4 or 8.0 you will have to specify the version in pecl.

```
pecl install sqlsrv-5.7.0preview
pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-5.7.0preview
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
phpenmod -v 7.1 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
service apache2 restart
```

The trick that got everything working was the printf and phpenmod command. You still need to add the extension to your php.ini file as well. Not sure if the order really matters but the driver does not appear to get installed properly using the pecl installer.

After restarting apache I can now see pdo_sqlsrv listed in php.ini and my php application can connect to the local Microsoft SQL server.

BTW, I got this working on WSL2 for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I solved this on CentOS 7.

First I've installed `pdo_dblib` extension

```
[root@localhost html]# yum list *dblib*
Complementos cargados:fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.airenetworks.es
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror.airenetworks.es
 * epel: ftp.uma.es
 * extras: mirror.airenetworks.es
 * remi-safe: mir01.syntis.net
 * updates: mirror.tedra.es
Paquetes instalados
php73-php-pdo-dblib.x86_64
Paquetes disponibles
php70-php-pdo-dblib.x86_64
php71-php-pdo-dblib.x86_64
php72-php-pdo-dblib.x86_64
php74-pdo-dblib.x86_64
php74-php-pdo-dblib.x86_64
php80-php-pdo-dblib.x86_64
php81-php-pdo-dblib.x86_64
[root@localhost html]# yum install php73-php-pdo-dblib.x86_64
```

I have php 7.3 installed so I've chosen matching version extension. After installation, tried a simple test script I created to test connectivity but still got error.

Used `locate` command to find out if pdo_dblib.so library was correctly installed and found it under /opt/remi/php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules path which looked a bit strange

With the command `locate php.ini` I discovered that there were 2 `php.ini` files on the machine. With the command `php -i` and by creating a simple file to test it from the web browser:

```
 <?php
phpinfo()
```

I checked what `php.ini` file was in use both from Cli and from Apache. It was `/etc/php.ini`.

With `php -m` I saw PDO was loading correctly, so I searched the location of `pdo.so` library. Copied `pdo_dblib.so` library on previous search location. Searched for `pdo_dblib.ini` file and copied it under the location of `pdo.ini` file (which full name was `20-pdo.ini`).

After all of these changes, restarted Apache `systemctl restart httpd` and checked again that pdo_dblib was loading both from cli and web whith `php -i` and the `phpinfo()`  file.

Comment: You are probably confused by multiple PHP stack, see https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl

Comment: For a proper configuration / installation, follow the wizard instructions: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

What you explain is a hack, not the proper way.